# How to load another sites content in an iframe?

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-domain, content-security-policy, same-origin-policy

I'm trying to iframe a pdf, the pdf is retrieved via AJAX which works fine because the server has CORs enabled (verified that I'm getting the pdf back via devtools).

But the result isn't able to be embedded in the iframe due to the following error:

```
Refused to frame '<SERVER_DOMAIN>' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'none'". Note that 'frame-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.
```

So I added the following meta tag to my page:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' <SERVER_DOMAIN>">
```

But still doesn't work. How to fix this?

Comment: Try setting the "frame-src" to "*" first and see if you can get it at all.

Comment: If you don't want to expose the actual url for that pdf source you could use a server side proxy to get the file contents and use that as iframe src. Might be easier than doing it with ajax

Comment: @JosefFazekas you mean like this? `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="frame-src:*">` that didn't work. What would the syntax look like?

Comment: <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="frame-src *"> can i ask why you aren't setting the CSP on the server side? Using a meta tag could not work when you are already received a CSP header when the server sends you a response (See Quentins answer)

Answer (score 0):

Since you said you **added** the meta tag, that means you must have already had a CSP from *some other source*.

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy#Multiple_content_security_policies):

> Adding additional policies can only further restrict the capabilities of the protected resource, which means that there will be no connection allowed and, as the strictest policy, connect-src 'none' is enforced.

You need to edit the *existing* policy to remove the restriction. You can't do it by adding an additional one.

Comment: Sorry if I'm misunderstanding what you're saying but there was no existent meta tag for content-security-policy, I added the only one.

Comment: @TK123 — Presumably the existing policy comes from an HTTP header then.